# Broadcast receiver for incoming call not working?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-broadcast

I am trying to display toast on incoming call received. but i am not getting any display. I have mention the receiver inside the manifest file which also contains permission required for phone calls.
the following is code that i have used.

```
// inside IncomingCall broadcastreceiver
package com.example.shailesh.callbroadcastreceiver;

 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
 import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call

        // get the phone number
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Call from:" +incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
            || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
        // This code will execute when the call is disconnected
        Toast.makeText(context, "Detected call hangup event", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

     }
 }
```

And i have specify in menifest file as follows :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".IncomingCall" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

what else i have to include in order to get toast display on incoming call received.
i Have also included following code in my `MainActivity`

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),IncomingCall.class);
    startService(i);
}
}
```

Comment: possibel duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/27107056/5515371

Comment: add package name to your receiver <receiver android:name="com.example.shailesh.callbroadcastreceiver.IncomingCall" android:enabled="true">

Comment: no still not working

Answer (score 2):

is class IncomingCall a service ? if not then why you are firing an intent to start service.

Comment: even i remove those line and rerun the project it does not give me any output when call receive..