# Broadcast receiver is not triggered for incoming calls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, incoming-call

I have this code and my app is not detecting the incoming calls.

My code is very similar with this answer what am i doing wrong?

[How does a Android "OS" detect a incoming call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105315/how-does-a-android-os-detect-a-incoming-call/27107056#27107056)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.reporting2you.r2ym">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.reporting2you.services.FloatingViewService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity android:name=".FloatingActivity" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.reporting2you.broadcastReceiver.CallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

BroadcastReceiver

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            Log.w("MY_DEBUG_TAG", state);
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, FloatingActivity.class));
                ((MainActivity)context).finish();
                String phoneNumber = extras
                        .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Log.w("MY_DEBUG_TAG", phoneNumber);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @GeniusQ Thank you now my problem is here: ((MainActivity)context).finish(); I cant cast it so how can i terminate my activity?

Comment: do you try to debug the app to check context is instanceof Activity or not?

Comment: nope i just supposed it once i only leave mainActivity on incomming call.

Comment: You can use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39130855/5282585. Or use custom listener to communicate between Activity and BroadcaseReceiver

Comment: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe

Comment: @Tiago_nes for safe side always use string constant as caller to avoid **Null Pointer Exception** ex - `if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` you need to request `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission first. 
Because `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` is dangerous level permission, so you must `checkSelfPermission()` in run time.

If not the broadcast will not be triggered when running on device with Android version above Marshmallow (23).

See: [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: question was of broadcast not triggered

Comment: @AbdulWaheed what do you mean? If he use `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` he need to request READ_PHONE_STATE. If not the broadcast will not be triggered.

Am I wrong?

Comment: What if he is targetting below marshmallow. The question was broadcast is not getting triggered. Find the reason why

Comment: mi minimum target is api 17

Comment: @Tiago_nes which Android version that your device in

Comment: emulator has api 26

Comment: @Tiago_nes So your device is higher than Android L, did you try my solution?

Comment: taking a look at it

Comment: You are welcome! @AbdulWaheed so now I found out why. xD

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE); //Change Here
            Log.w("MY_DEBUG_TAG", state);
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, FloatingActivity.class));
                ((MainActivity)context).finish();
                String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER); //Change Here
                Log.w("MY_DEBUG_TAG", phoneNumber);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't intent.getExtras().getString() equal to intent.getStringExtra() ?